# Search if multiple substrings are present on a row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I've made the following code to search for an specific keyword on a row in a sheet:

```
function findNios() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('DataSheet');
  var r = s.getRange(2,11,s.getLastRow() - 1,1);
  var v = r.getValues();
  var searchTerm = "nios";  
  const result = v.map(row => row[0].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) > 1 ? ["Present"]: ["NO"])
  r.offset(0,35).setValues(result)
}
```

However this is only for one keyword in specific as defined here:

`var searchTerm = "nios";`

And now I want to add several terms to the search, so for example I have the following substrings that I want to search and if one isn't found proceed to look to the other term:

`var searchTerms = "nios", "blob": ,"centre";`

Is there a way to make this work with multiple terms?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to perform a seach for multiple words.  Note however that this will match a word like niossy.

I made a test sheet as shown.

[image]

Next the script.

```
function findNios() {
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s = ss.getSheetByName('DataSheet');
    //var r = s.getRange(2,11,s.getLastRow() - 1,1);
    var r = s.getRange(2,1,s.getLastRow() - 1,1);
    var v = r.getValues();
    var searchTerms = ["nios", "blob","centre"];
    const result = v.map( row => {
        let found = ["NO"];
        searchTerms.some( term => {
            if( row[0].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(term) > 0 ) {
              found = ["Present"];
              return true;
            }
            return false;
          }
        );
        return found;
      }
    );
    console.log(result);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

The execution log

```
7:37:36 AM  Notice  Execution started
7:37:38 AM  Info    [ [ 'NO' ],
  [ 'Present' ],
  [ 'NO' ],
  [ 'Present' ],
  [ 'NO' ],
  [ 'NO' ],
  [ 'Present' ],
  [ 'NO' ] ]
7:37:37 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Reference

- [Array.some()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_some.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this but it looks like it might work:

```
function findNios() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('DataSheet');
  var rg = sh.getRange(2, 11, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 1);
  var vs = rg.getValues();
  var searchTerm = ["nios"];//add more words here
  searchTerm.forEach((st, i) => {
    let result = vs.map(row => row[0].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(st) > -1 ? ["Present"] : ["NO"]);
    result.unshift(st);
    rg.offset(-1, 35 + i).setValues(result);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function findTerms() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('DataSheet');
  var r = s.getRange(2,11,s.getLastRow() - 1,1);
  var v = r.getValues();
  var searchTerms = ["nios", "blob" ,"centre"]  
  const result = v.map(row => searchTerms.some(term => 
    row[0].toString().toLowerCase().includes(term))? ["Present"]:["NO"])
  r.offset(0,35).setValues(result)
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use `or` operator `|` of [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) with [regex.test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

```
const searchTerms = /nios|blob|centre/;  
const result = v.map(([e]) =>
   searchTerms.test(e) ? ["Present"] : ["No"])
```